# Preload all associations with an order_by

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework, ecto

This is what I'm trying to do:

```
project =
      Repo.get!(Project, id)
      |> Repo.preload([rows: from(r in Row, order_by: r.index)] [images: from(i in Image, order_by: i.index)])
```

But I'm getting this error:

```
** (ArgumentError) the Access calls for keywords expect the key to be an atom, got: [images: #Ecto.Query<from i in Dreamhouse.Image, order_by: [asc: i.index]>]
```

Does anybody know what I'm doing wrong here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error message says, that you're trying to get an element from a keyword-list, but passing something unexpected instead of an atom.

For example, the following code produces a similar error:

```
keyword_list = [keyword: :argument]
keyword_list[unexpected: :structure]
```

So the problem is in this line:

```
Repo.preload([rows: from(r in Row, order_by: r.index)] [images: from(i in Image, order_by: i.index)])
```

You might want to provide one keyword list as an argument with all the associations you want to preload:

```
Repo.preload([rows: from(r in Row, order_by: r.index), images: from(i in Image, order_by: i.index)])
```

Answer (score 3):

I doubt I can explain the error message, but the reason is:

```
[rows: from(...)] [images: from(...)]
```

is not a valid Elixir. Check:

```
[[foo: 42] [bar: 3.14]]
```

It should be:

```
[rows: from(...), images: from(...)]
```